# highcharts / highstock doesn't show markers after 500 pts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

It seems that over 500 points causes our highstocks markers not to show at all - you can see 
http://www.ethnographicedge.com/topic/senkaku-trial-400/ (400 pts) vs http://www.ethnographicedge.com/topic/senkaku-trial-600-s1/ (600pts).  The data that's not showing is the "event" represented by the green sphere.

I've looked into editing the turboThreshold, but no luck..

Here's a simplified jsfiddle, and my full code below:

jsfiddle.net/marquex/etdL7/1

when you change the var points = 200; to 400, the red dot doesn't display. Is there a way to force certain mandatory points to show, regardless of the data size?

```
graphdata = <?php echo topic_data(get_the_ID()); ?>;
    extradata = <?php echo extra_data(get_the_ID()); ?>;
    eventdata = <?php global $events; echo json_encode($events) ?>;
    eventdata.sort(function(a,b){
        return a.date - b.date;
    });

;(function($){
    var parseData,
        container = $('#graphcontainer'),
        last = false,
        m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December");
    ;
    if(! container.length)
        return;

    getEventPoint = function(e,idx){
        var color = 'gray';
        if(e.forecast == 'fore_successful_down')
            color = 'red';
        else if(e.forecast == 'fore_successful_up')
            color = 'green';

        return {
            x: parseInt(e.stringdate),
            y: parseInt(e.value),
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                radius:8,
                fillColor: color,
                lineWidth:3,
                lineColor: 'white',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        radius:8,
                        fillColor: 'white',
                        lineWidth:3,
                        lineColor: color
                    }
                }
            },
            name: idx
        }
    }

    dateDay = function(day){
        if( day % 10 == 1)
            return day + 'st';
        if( day % 10 == 2)
            return day + 'nd';
        if( day % 10 == 3)
            return day + 'rd';
        return day + 'th';
    }

    formatDate = function(timestamp){
        var date = new Date(timestamp);
        return m_names[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getDay() + ', ' + date.getFullYear();
    }

    tooltipFormatter = function(data){
        var point = data.points[0],
            name = point.point.name,
            output = '<div class="tooltip-date">' + formatDate(data.x) + '</div><div class="tooltip-value"><span class="tooltip-unit"><?php the_field("value_text") ?>:</span> ' + data.y + '</div>';

        if(typeof name !== "undefined"){
            var e = eventdata[name];
            return '<div class="tooltip-date">' + formatDate(data.x) + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="tooltip-title">' + e.number + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="tooltip-trend tooltip-' + e.trend + '"></div> <!-- I will resize the image > background-size: -->' +
                    '<div class="tooltip-cycle">' + e.cycle + '</div>';
        }

        if(data.points[1])
            output += '<div class="tooltip-secondary><div class="tooltip-value"><span class="tooltip-unit"><?php the_field("extra_value_text") ?>:</span> ' + data.points[1].y + '</div>'

        return output;
    }

    parseData = function(data, eventsData){
        var parsedData = [],
            eventIdx = 0,
            events = eventsData ? eventsData.slice(0) : [],
            e = events[0]
        ;
        if(e)
            e.stringdate = (new Date(e.date.substring(0,4) + '/' + e.date.substring(4,6) + '/' + e.date.substring(6,8))).getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var item = data[i],
                timestamp = false;
            if(item.date && item.date.match(/^\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) && item.value && parseFloat(item.value) == item.value){

                timestamp = (new Date(item.date)).getTime();
                if(e && timestamp > e.stringdate > last) {
                    parsedData.push(getEventPoint(e, eventIdx));
                    parsedData.push([timestamp, parseFloat(item.value)]);
                    e = events[++eventIdx];
                    if(e)
                        e.stringdate = (new Date(e.date.substring(0,4) + '/' + e.date.substring(4,6) + '/' + e.date.substring(6,8))).getTime();
                }
                else if(e && timestamp == e.stringdate) {
                    parsedData.push(getEventPoint(e, eventIdx));
                    e = events[++eventIdx];
                    if(e)
                        e.stringdate = (new Date(e.date.substring(0,4) + '/' + e.date.substring(4,6) + '/' + e.date.substring(6,8))).getTime();
                }
                else
                    parsedData.push([timestamp, parseFloat(item.value)]);
            }
        };
        while(e){
            parsedData.push(getEventPoint(e, eventIdx));
            e = events[++eventIdx];
            if(e)
                e.stringdate = (new Date(e.date.substring(0,4) + '/' + e.date.substring(4,6) + '/' + e.date.substring(6,8))).getTime();
        }
        return parsedData;
    };


 var series = [{
        name: 'Topic Data',
        data: parseData(graphdata, eventdata),
        color: '#666'
 }];

        if(extradata && extradata.length){
            series.push({
                name: 'Extra Data',
                data: parseData(extradata),
                yAxis: 1,
                color: '#fbb800'
            });
        }

        var yAxis = [{
            title: {
                text: '<?php the_field("value_text") ?>',
                style: { color: '#BBBBBB', fontSize: '1.2em' },
                margin: 12,
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false,
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value
                }
            },
            height: 300,
            lineColor: '#FFFFFF'

        }];

        if(extradata && extradata.length){
            yAxis[0].lineWidth = 2;

            yAxis.push({
                title: {
                    text: '<?php the_field("extra_value_text") ?>'
                },
                height: 200,
                top:350,
                offset:0,
                lineWidth:2,
                lineColor: '#FFFFFF'
            });

        }

    container.highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            events: {
                load: function(e){
                    $('#tapapubli')
                        .detach()
                        .addClass('tapapubli')
                        .appendTo('#graphcontainer');
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            enabled: false,
            buttons:[
                {
                    type: '<?php echo $initial_zoom["type"] ?>',
                    count: <?php echo $initial_zoom["count"] ?>,
                    text: 'Initial'
                },
                {
                    type: 'All',
                    text: 'Reset'
                }
            ],
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: false,
        },
         navigator: {
            maskFill: 'rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.75)',
            series: {
                color: '#FFD600',
                lineColor: '#AE8800'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
        labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            lineColor: '#FFF', /* BITBUCKET */
            tickColor: '#666666',
            tickLength: 0,
            tickWidth: 1,
            tickPosition: 'outside',
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            day: '%e of %b',
            }
        },
        yAxis: yAxis,
        plotOptions: {
        lineColor: 'green',
            spline: {
                lineWidth: 3,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 3
                    }
                },

                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                pointInterval: 36000000000,
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function(){
                            //console.log(this);
                            if(this.name)
                                window.location.href = '#event-' + eventdata[this.name].number;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

            series: series,

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function(){
                return tooltipFormatter(this);
            },
            useHTML: true,
            borderColor: '#333',
            shadow: false,
            borderRadius: 0
        }
    });
    if(!window.chart)
        window.chart = container.highcharts();
})(jQuery);

var getPointRecursive = function(date, list){
    if(list.length < 5){
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var point = list[i];
        };
    }
}
var getSeriesPoint = function(date){

}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code, which can be a good thing, and can also be very difficult to read. If you have a good idea of where the problem lies, you may want to consider putting it into a separate block or removing the non-applicable code. Otherwise a great first question!

Comment: Could you isolate your example from additional funtions, and prepare simple example?

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with a simple example - http://jsfiddle.net/marquex/etdL7/1/
when you change the var points = 200; to 400, the red dot doesn't display.  Is there a way to force certain mandatory points to show, regardless of the data size?

Comment: @mangroveweb, after playing around with the data points and the size of the window, it seems it has more to do with the size of the graph v. the number of data points. I found that when the actual width of the chart element in the Javascript iframe was definitely greater than 2 times the number of data points, the marker would display. For instance, you can set the number of data points to 600 and then expand the JS frame to > 1300 px and you will see your markers. Not sure why, but might get you on the right path.

Comment: thanks @StephenH - seeing that there will eventually be up to 10k points on this, it would be really great to not have to hack the width to accommodate, and instead somehow enable the event points to always show (as there will probably never be more than 100 events).  anyone at #highcharts know any way around this? js fiddle here: jsfiddle.net/marquex/etdL7/1  thanks!

Comment: Markers are not displayed, because when you have many points, the datagrouping is enabled. So markers are skipped which you have. http://jsfiddle.net/etdL7/2/

Answer (score 0):

As @Sebastian Bochan said, you just need to set `plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled = false` explicitly. Then the problem will disappear.